# Adding row to jqm grid

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to know how to add a row to a grid. I declared ui-grid-b with 3 columns. I need 8 buttons in this grid in my footer. How to do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. I recommend that you read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq in order to learn how to properly ask questions. In this case, it would be great if you show us some code and explain further what you want to accomplish. That way, people will be able to give you better advices and you can show that you have put some effort in solving this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about it in jQueryMobile docs. Basically "grids are designed to wrap to multiple rows of items. For example, if you specify a 3-column grid (ui-grid-b) on a container that has nine child blocks, it will wrap to 3 rows of 3 items each." You should also read about toolbars. It may be usefull for a good start.

There is a full explaination:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/content/content-grids.html